# Momentjs: format date with timezone?

Tags: date, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to so something very simple and surely people have soled this before:

I have a date string (from Facebook API) that looks like `2015-09-08T19:05:00-0400`.

I want to use `moment.calendar` to format this string along with the timezone abbreviation. Something like "Tomorrow at 7pm EST". Right now its saying "Tomorrow at 4pm" since I'm in PST.

This has proven to be a challenging problem. It seems that as soon as you do `time = moment("2015-09-08T19:05:00-0400")`, then `time` has lost all timezone information since the date was converted immediately into my local timezone.

I'd prefer not to use moment-timezone as this use-case seems incredibly simple. I'm considering manually parsing the last 5 digits and adding the abbreviation myself, but thats a complete hack. Surely there must be a better way of doing this. That said, there seems to be a lot of commotion about this. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `parseZone` function will have the resulting `moment` object retain the offset provided, rather than using the local time zone.

```
moment.parseZone("2015-09-08T19:05:00-0400").calendar()
```

You also asked for it to return the time zone abbreviation `"EST"`, however that is not possible.  One cannot assume that an offset belongs to a specific time zone, because the offset may be in use by several different time zones, each having different abbreviations.